# How to get a complete column of emails from mysql table to a CSV file

Tags: php, mysql, file, csv, field

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql dump to localhost outfile from a remote database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743419/mysql-dump-to-localhost-outfile-from-a-remote-database)

I have a mysql table with email as a field. I want to get all those email to a CSV file so that i can use the emails for newsletter purpose.

I tried the export option in MySQL but i couldn't figure out how to select just one field from the whole table.

Can anyone help me how to do this? I guess it's a simple trick but i guess i am too beginner for this as well!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125113/php-code-to-convert-a-mysql-query-to-csv

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing the MySQL database locally, then Besnik's link to the other thread will work.

Remotely however is a different story and you will want to do something like this...

[mysql dump to localhost outfile from a remote database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743419/mysql-dump-to-localhost-outfile-from-a-remote-database)