# cant create file when trying to mysqldump to csv on remote server

Tags: bash, csv, batch-file, mysql

So I have a batch server that runs a batch script.  This script issues a mysqldump command for our db server.

```
 mysqldump -h nnn.nn.nnn.nn -u username -p password --tab=/var/batchfiles/ --fields-enclosed-by='"' --fields-terminated-by="," --fields-escaped-by="\\" --lines-terminated-by="\\n" store_locations stores
```

When the command runs, I get an error:

```
Can't create/write to file '/var/mi6/batch/stores.txt' (Errcode: 2) when executing 'SELECT INTO OUTFILE'
```

Now I have tried also outputting to the /tmp dir as suggested at http://techtots.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-mysqldump-to-export-csv-file.html and it is still unable to write the file as it tells me it already exists, even though it doesn't.

Bottom line is, I would like to be able run a script on server A that issues a mysql command for the db server and have that output file saved to server A in csv format.

FYI, I have also tried just running mysql and redirecting output to a file.  This creates a tab file but you dont have much control over the output which so it wont really work either.

Comment: Is it a batch file or a bash script? Mind posting it please? Also, do you run the script as a user when enough permissions for `/var/mi6/batch/`? And even `/var/mi6/batch/stores.txt` if the file exists.

Comment: well, actually, you could remove the batch script from the equation.  If you just try to run the mysqldump command by itself, it has the issue.  And I tried changing the perms for /var/mi6/batch/ to 777 and the issue remained.  I did the same with the stores.txt file and also completely deleted the stores.txt file to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mysqldump` in a `--tab` mode is a CLI tool for `SELECT INTO OUTFILE`. And the latter is normally supposed to be used to create a delimited file afresh and **only on the db server host.**

> **[SELECT ... INTO Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-into.html)**
>   The SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE statement is intended primarily to let you
>   very quickly dump a table to a text file **on the server machine**. If you
>   want to create the resulting file on some other host than the server
>   host, you normally **cannot use SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE since there is
>   no way to write a path to the file relative to the server host's file
>   system.**

You have at least following options:

1. use `mysql` instead of `mysqldump` on a remote host to create a tab delimited file instead

   ```
   mysql -h<host> -u<user> -p<password> \
   -e "SELECT 'column_name', 'column_name2'... \
       UNION ALL SELECT column1, column2, FROM stores" > \
   /path/to/your/file/file_name
   ```
2. you can pipe it with `sed` or `awk` and create a CSV file from a tab delimited output. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4743557/1920232) for details
3. you can make a location for a file on a remote host accessible through network-mapped path on db server's file system.

Comment: i adjusted the sed command to handle quotes that were already in strings:  's/"/\""/g;s/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/\n//g'